# SignalR client's InvokeAync returns null

Tags: signalr, .net-5

Per the MS documentation for `InvokeAsync`:

> The InvokeAsync method returns a Task which completes when the server method returns. The return value, if any, is provided as the result of the Task.

And for 'SendAsync`

> The SendAsync method returns a Task which completes when the message has been sent to the server. No return value is provided since this Task doesn't wait until the server method completes.

However in my testing it does not seem to be the case. It always returns null, regardless of what the server sends AND then disconnects from the hub.

How to get the server-sent value using `InvokeAsync`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've misunderstood how the `HubConnection` API works and that's what caused the confusion for me. In the hub in my server I had defined the method like this:

```
public async Task Receive() 
{
    var data = new Dto();
    this.Clients.All.Receive(data);
}
```

This kind of definition is intended to call a "Receive" procedure on all clients. I.e. `connection.On("Receive", () => {...})`. However `InokeAsync` is intended to return the literal server method response, which in this case is a `Task`. When it attempts to serialize the task object to my DTO it fails, thus retuning null and breaking the hub connection.

There are two ways to solve the problem:

1. Use `SendAsync` and rely on the "Receive" procedure to receive the data
2. Change the definition of the server Hub method to directly return the desired data, rather than using it's `Clients` API:

```
    public Dto Receive()
    {
        return new Dto();
    }
```